# Portion of PDF missing in QGIS Export to PDF

Tags: qgis, pdf

I'm trying to produce a custom sized PDF (841 x 3567mm). The preview in QGIS composer looks fine but when the Export to PDF is completed I'm missing the bottom portion of the PDF image.
The composition is comprised of vector and raster layers (ECW) and some of the vector have a transparency setting. I've trying turning off the transparency to see if it is having an affect but still getting the same output, so it doesn't seem to be related.
See image attached.[image]

[image]

Comment: I might have a similar problem.  When I export to PDF, the scalebar block goes OK but the numeric units seem to be "left behind".  The Atlas preview done before the export appears just fine with the units showing.  Using QGIS 3.0.2 on Windows10 Pro 64-bit.

Comment: @GrahamDee63, Did you ever resolve this issue? Was it version-specific or does it persist into current versions of QGIS?

Comment: @csk, Sorry, it's been sometime and I don't recall if I ever fixed the issue?

Comment: Fair enough. The system bumped your question up to the front page so I thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of QGIS are you using ? It's maybe not the most appropriate answer for your case but I solved most (let's say all) of these problems using the **64 bit** version of QGIS.

Answer (score 0):

This is a know issue coming from Qt. Since exporting relies on a single QPainterthe requested export can hit the limitation ( https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpainter.html#limitations ). The solution may be to lower the resolution or fix/fund a fix to stich images when it exeeds the size limitation of QPainter.